# How to check date range in mssql for epoch datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

in one of the table the date column values are like below

```
 date
25052008112228
26052008062717
```

table name is transaction

i tried using the below query but its throwing error

```
select * from transaction where date between '2012-01-06' and '2012-06-30'

select * from transaction where date between '2012/01/06' and '2012/06/30'
```

give me a solution.

Comment: i found its not unixtimestamp. it seems asp timestamp. can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

-- asp time stamp

```
 select  * from [transaction] where 
    cast(SUBSTRING([date],5,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING([date],3,2) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING([date],1,2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([date],9,2) + 
    ':' + SUBSTRING([date],11,2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING([date],13,2) as datetime)
between '2008-05-26' and  '2012-01-06'
```

-- unix epoch time

```
 select * from [transaction] where  [date] 
 between DATEDIFF( SECOND, '01-01-1970 00:00:00', '2012-01-06' ) 
 and DATEDIFF( SECOND, '01-01-1970 00:00:00', '2012-06-30')
```

Comment: thanks for the query. But its not working. i got this error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.'

Comment: @agurchand: please chaeck now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [date] column doesn't contain a date in a format that will be automatically converted to an appropriate `datetime` value - it doesn't even contain a *supported* format value. So you're left shredding the text using string operations:

```
declare @Transactions table (TDate char(14))
insert into @Transactions (TDate) values
('25052008112228'),
('26052008062717')

select CONVERT(datetime,
    SUBSTRING(TDate,5,4) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(TDate,3,2) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(TDate,1,2) + 'T' +
    SUBSTRING(TDate,9,2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(TDate,11,2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(TDate,13,2))
from
    @Transactions
```

Results:

```
2008-05-25 11:22:28.000
2008-05-26 06:27:17.000
```

You could wrap the `CONVERT/SUBSTRING` operations into a UDF, if you need to perform this kind of conversion often. Of course, ideal would be to change the column definition to store a genuine `datetime` value - almost all `datetime` issues arise when people treat them as text.

(Note, I've renamed both the table and the column, since using reserved words is usually a bad idea)

---

Your query could be something like:

```
;with converted as (
     select *,CONVERT(datetime,
            SUBSTRING([Date],5,4) + '-' +
            SUBSTRING([Date],3,2) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING([Date],1,2) + 'T' +
        SUBSTRING([Date],9,2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING([Date],11,2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING([Date],13,2)) as GenuineDate
     from [Transaction]
)
select * from converted where GenuineDate between '20120106' and '20120630'
```

(Note that I've also changed the date literals in the final query to a safe format also)